# jQuery - handle child-click depending on parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have some trouble here using js/jquery:

I have parent LIs with several different child elements in it. Now every child element has an own attached event-handler. What i need now is to call an event of the parent if it misses some class, and call the (clicked) child's event if the parent has that class:

```
<div id="parent" class="expanded">
  <span class="child1"></span>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <font class="child3"></font>
</div>
```

Now i only want to execute each child-events if the parent container misses the class "*expanded*". If the parent is "expanded" i need to allow the executed functions.

Now sure it's easy to ask for that class in every single handler on the child elements, but i think there could be a much better solution using only one handler that decides and bubbles/stopBubble the event. Do you know any nice solution?

### Found Solution:

Easy to say, the key is Capturing. Since jQuery does not support capturing (bubbling the other direction: From parent to child) i can use this *workaround*:

Now it works adding this to the beginning of my code:

```
$('#parent').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('expanded')) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return getTicket(e, $(this)).toggleVisibility();
        }
    }, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".child").click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("expanded"))
    {
       //do parent stuff with $(this).parent()
    }
    else
    {
       //do child stuff with $(this)
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 I'd use $(this).closest('#parent') for parent though. Just in case there are more level later on.

Comment: Thanks. Sure this would work but also need me to change and add this to every single child-event handler. Is there any "more global" solution? Every child has different identifers and events.

Comment: You have to identify and select them somehow. What is common about the child elements?

Comment: @xyc7e for me this looks like an acceptable global solution **according to the details provided in question**. You should provide more accurate info to get more accurate answer..

Comment: Imagine a list of "tickets" having some content buttons. I only want that buttons be functional if the ticket of the list has been "expanded". If not, the click on the child element should expand the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate child event handlers already defined;
 You can create a generic child event handler and throw a user exception(When its parent is not *expanded*) to prevent further child-specific events

```
$(".child").on("click", function (e) {
    //If parent does not have class expanded
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("expanded")) 
        throw {}
});


/* Child handlers already defined */

$("span.child").on("click", function (e) {
    console.log('span');

});
$("div.child").on("click", function (e) {
    console.log('div');
});

/**/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ujjx8/2/

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use .parent().not() api to achieve your objective; like below:

```
$(".child").parent().not(".expanded").click(function(){
      // code to  parent which is not having class expanded should go here.
}
```